# Check if MyInterface is instanceof type MyClass<T>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have something like this:

I found similar question on SO: [How can I check if element is an instanceof U?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392349/how-can-i-check-if-element-is-an-instanceof-u) , 
but it just shows how to implement `OfType<T>`, not `OfType<T<U>>`

```
export class Foo implements IFoo
{
    private _items:Array<MyInterface> = new Array<MyInterface>();

    public Something = () =>
    {
       var myTypes = this.OfType<MyClass<TestModel>>(this._items);
    }

    private OfType = <T>(items:any[]) => 
    {
      //here i would like to return all this._items that are T
    }
}


export class TestModel
{

}

export class MyClass<T>
{

}
```

How would I detect if class is of type `T<U>`? 
Is this event possible, I am willing to implement hacks if nessecery?

Comment: JsLinq has an implementation of OfType. Also, check out my idea in LINQ-to-TypeScript.

Comment: @StephenChung Did you mean http://jslinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Nuget/package/Content/Scripts/JSLINQ.js ? I can't find OfType, besides existing js libraries cannot work with typescript generics because they are erased at compile. It has to be some kind of pattern for passing types to objects.

Comment: Oops.  I meant Linqjs.  Sorry!  Linqjs is a full implementation of LINQ, including the OfType operator.  There are TypeScript definition files for it.

Comment: From my LINQ-to-TypeScript project, I think I defined ``OfType`` as taking a parameter of type ``Function`` (all JavaScript classes are functions) and then using ``instanceof`` in the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have reflection like C# does, and is not able to detect if a class is of type T.
The only way to test if a JavaScript object implements an interface is to use [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  i.e. if an object looks like a duck, walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it is a duck.

In their book, "[Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](http://jsdesignpatterns.com/)", Ross Harmes and Dustin Diaz explain how determine if a class implements an interface by testing properties and methods on the given class.

Have a look at my blog on this JavaScript pattern - which shows [how to implement run-time type checking](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/typescript-implementing-a-simple-ioc-container-for-service-location/) ( reflection of sorts ) in TypeScript.